# Can you add and sort by multiple columns in php?

Tags: php

I'd like to add the results of one column based on another column and show results in order.

I'm looking to see if the top 2 scores for each team can be added together and then sorted based on which team got the highest combined score.

Table information:

```
team1score   -   1000
team1score   -   1500
team1score   -   1600
team2score   -   1700
team2score   -   1800
team2score   -   1900
team3score   -   1100
team3score   -   1200
team3score   -   1300
```

Any direction whether it is some kind of built in PHP or possibly some kind of select string sort magic. I am just not sure on the best direction to go at this point.

The results I'd like to show are:

```
team2score - 37
team1score - 31
team3score - 25
```

Comment: How is your desired result related to the source data? I don't see anything in the source that could possibly result in the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to do that directly, but you can write a program to do it easily. What I would do is create an array of all the key values based on the original array, storing the scores as an array:

```
// Assume $scores is your original array with team in index 0 and score in index 1
// I will turn it into $a[team] = array(score, score, score...)
$a = array();
foreach($scores as $teamscore) {
  $team = $teamscore[0];
  $score = $teamscore[1];
  if(!isset($a[$team])) $a[$team] = array();
  $a[$team][] = $score;
}
```

Now, I want to convert each array of scores into the sum of the top two scores. That is easy if I reverse sort each one. Then, I can sum up index 0 and index 1.

```
foreach($a as $team=>$scores) {
  rsort($scores);
  $a[$team] = $scores[0] + $scores[1];
  // I assumed there are at least 2 scores per team
}
```

Finally, you can reverse sort $a keeping key association.

```
arsort($a);
foreach($a as $team=>$sum) {
  print "$team\t$sum\n";
}
```

I did this in a very verbose manner in hope that it makes a lot of sense. It is trivial to drastically reduce the lines of code by combining the instructions together. Further, if you want the displayed score to be the sum divided by 100, you can easily print $sum/100 instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is in MySQL (unclear), then a query like the following should return an array of the top 3 scores in descending order that you could then loop through:

```
SELECT  team_score, right(trim(team_score), length(trim(team_score)) - locate('-',team_score) -1) + 0 as just_score from table order by just_score DESC LIMIT 3
```